# How do I resolve the retrieval error in my Android studio code?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I have used authentication on Firebase. After authentication, a form is to be filled by the user, but only once. If the form is already filled (user id  exists), I want to skip that activity. Below is the code that crashes the app after authentication :

```
String ret_id= firebaseAuth.getUid();

databaseUsers.child("users").child(ret_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Profile prof= dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
                String check= prof.id;

                if(check.isEmpty())
                {
            startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
                else
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
```

Comment: Share your error please

Comment: I've added the image of error, sorry for the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a mistake by using both **getReference(*"users"*)** and **child(*"users"*)** in subsequent step. Here is the correct code.

```
String ret_id= firebaseAuth.getUid();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(ret_id).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String ret_name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String ret_rid=dataSnapshot.child("rid").getValue().toString();
                String ret_phone=dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();

                if(!ret_rid.isEmpty())
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code crash  because prof is null and you try get its id for avoid

```
 Profile prof= dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
 if(prof==null||TextUtils.isEmpty(prof.id)){
     startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
     return;
  }
 String check= prof.id;
```

Comment: 'return' is making the page transition to same page and it goes on infinitely. When return is taken off, the app crashes again.

Comment: Without the Profile.class, this can be done, but it still crashes; "String ret_name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString()"